# Plotly.js Scatter Polar - Change units and add color to points

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to plot some colours on a scatter polar chart in Plotly, using Javascript only. I can't seem to figure out how to change the scale, or add individual colors to my points.

Here's what I'm trying to do

**1. Fix units:**

- Angular axis units from 0 to 100
- Angular axis straight up (north) starts at 0
- Angular axis show ticks every 5 units = every 18 degrees
- Radial axis units from 0 to 18

**2. Individual Colors for the plot circle of each value

- Cadmium red =  #dd3a3a
- Cobalt blue = #241fff
- Viridian = #24723a

[Example of what I want:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PmbB.png)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title> Colour Chart</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chartContainer"></div>

    <script src="js/plotly-2.26.0.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script>

     var data = [
        {
        type: "scatterpolar",
        mode: "markers+text",
        r: [16,12,4],
        theta: [7.5,76.25,57.5],
        text: ["Cadmium Red", "Cobalt Blue", "Viridian"],
        textposition: "right",
        line: {
            color: "#ff66ab"
        },
        marker: {
            color: "#000000",
            symbol: "circle",
            size: 8
        },
        subplot: "polar"
        }
    ]

    var layout = {
        showlegend: false,
        polar: {
        domain: {
            x: [0,1],
            y: [0,1]
        },
        radialaxis: {
            tickfont: {
            size: 8
            }
        },
        angularaxis: {
            tickfont: {
            size: 8
            },
            rotation: 90,
            direction: "counterclockwise"
        }
        }
    }

    Plotly.newPlot("chartContainer", data, layout)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've looked at the documentation but I can't seem to figure it out.